# Unable to get a Window, abort. in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
         b1 = Button(text='A')
         b2 = Button(text='B')
         self.add_widget(b1)
         self.add_widget(b2)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

in this case, I couldn't get the new app window, an error. and actually, I didn't understand it

Comment: super().__init__(**kwargs): 

this line is not working i don't know why

Comment: Do you have any `.kv` file ?

Comment: what is the error message please ?

Comment: `Exception has occurred: SystemExit
1
TheLabApp().run()`

Comment: `# :2.0.0 kivy


MainWidget:


<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
        color: 'yellow'
        size: "40dp"," 40dp"
        pos: "100dp","200dp"
    Label:
        text: "1st Button"
        color: 'red'
        size: '100dp','80dp'
        pos: '200dp','300dp'
`

my kivy file

Comment: `[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.`